# Using multiple controllers inside of one view

Tags: php, laravel

I Need some advice, as I'm still a bit new to Laravel and MVC in general. I'm coding a small web application that presents some data on the page, fetched from a remote API. However, the page already has a controller to it. The other controller I will be using I'm hoping I can also reuse it for other pages. I'm pretty stuck here.

So the two controllers

```
HomeController.php 
ApiController.php
```

The HomeController is the original controller, which gets the view file (`home.blade.php`), with some other data that's being loaded from the controller.

With the ApiController, I want to fetch the api (json) results, do some changes and then load those changes to the HomeController as well. The changes would be like an array of methods and such that's being loaded to the view.

So How can I load both controllers inside of the same view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all controllers doesn't get loaded inside `view` instead, you should load a `view` from a `controller` and to make the remote request for an `API` call you don't need to use another controller but you may use it if you have other use of `API` and need a separate controller. The flow is something like this:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        // make the api call/remote request
        // modify the returned data
        // load the view
    }

}
```

Let's rewrite it:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    protected $apiService = null;

    public function __construct(ApiService $apiService)
    {
        $this->apiService = $apiService;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        // make the api call/remote request
        $apiData = $this->apiService->makeRequest();

        // modify the returned data.... then...

        // load the view
        return View::make(...)->with('apiData', $apiData);
    }

}
```

So, it seems clear that, you should use the `API` related process in a separate class as a service, maybe a model or a simple repository class and inject it to your `HomeController` then use it from the controller.

Do all the API stuffs in ApiService and call methods of that class from the `HomeController`, in this case you may implement the `ApiServiceRepository` as a concrete class by implementing an interface, i.e. `ApiService`. So, finally it could be like this:

```
interface ApiService {
    public function makeRequest();
}

// Implement the interface in concrete class
class ApiServiceRepository implements ApiService {

    public function makeRequest()
    {
        // $data = make remote request
        // return $data
    }
}
```

Use the class `HomeController` with `__construct` as given above and add a `IoC` binding like:

```
App::bind('ApiService', 'ApiServiceRepository');
```

So, you don't have to worry about the dependency injection in the constructor of your `HomeController`.

BTW, to use a method from another controller, for example `ApiController` from `HomeController` you may use something like this:

```
$apiController = App::make('ApiController');

// Call any method of "ApiController" class/object
$apidata = $apiController->makeCallToMethod();
```

You may also check [this article](http://heera.it/laravel-repository-pattern) for understanding the use of repository pattern in `Laravel`.

Comment: To be honest, I'm really confused, but I'll try to understand this. thanks.

Comment: Question, where would the interface files go?

Comment: Anywhere but accessible by your `ApiServiceRepository` class.

Comment: Look into "namespacing," but `app`, `app/models`, and `app/controllers`, for instance. On a small project you could leave them in `app/controllers`, but on anything "real" I'd look into a custom namespace with good organization.